# Ocelot API gateway setting only TimeOut value throwing error

Tags: asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

According to Ocelot document [Quality Of Service](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/qualityofservice.html) we can metion only TimeOutValue in Routes, like

```
"QoSOptions": {
    "TimeoutValue":5000
}
```

but this is throwing exception like

```
Ocelot.Requester.Middleware.HttpRequesterMiddleware: Debug: requestId: 800002b3-0002-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: IHttpRequester returned an error, setting pipeline error
Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware: Warning: requestId: 800002b3-0002-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToCompleteRequestError Message: Error making http request, exception: System.ArgumentException: The enumerable of policies to form the wrap must contain at least two policies. (Parameter 'policies')
   at Polly.Policy.WrapAsync(IAsyncPolicy[] policies)
   at Ocelot.Provider.Polly.PollyCircuitBreakingDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Ocelot.Requester.HttpClientHttpRequester.GetResponse(HttpContext httpContext) errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/api/v1/cust/clients, request method: GET
Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: Debug: requestId: 800002b3-0002-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline finished
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 200.2779ms 500
```

My Route configuration is

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/cust/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/cust/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [],
      "QoSOptions": {
        "TimeoutValue": 900000
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
  }
}
```

My .Net Core version is 3.1 and Ocelet version is 16.0.1

Comment: It looks like this might be a Polly issue: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some issue by having only one policy (the timeout policy).

I have to add the Circuit Break settings to make this work:

```
 "QoSOptions": {
    "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking":99999,
    "DurationOfBreak":0,
    "TimeoutValue":5000
  }
```

Comment: Bro, you dont have any idea what you saved, thank you for it.